# No ApplicationRoleManager class in my MVC 5 Identity 2 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identity

I am trying to implement roles in a project using VS 2013 Update 2. The project itself is MVC 5 with Identity 2.0... The standard web template that comes out of the box. Yet while going through tutorials online, I keep seeing them reference a ApplicationRoleManager class. This class is not defined by default in my projects, anyone have any ideas why? Or how to fix it?

**Update**
Also in my IdentityConfig.cs class under my App_Start folder, the only classes contained are:
.ApplicationUserManager
.EmailService
.SmsService

Comment: I'm really new to asp.net however from what I can see it may be features that were changed between Identity 2.0 and 2.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's seems it's been a part of one of the versions of mvc template in VS but it's just a shortcut to for RoleManager

```
public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<IdentityRole>
{
    public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<IdentityRole,string> roleStore)
        : base(roleStore)
    {
    }
}
```